# Importing Excel data to python with openpyxl

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, openpyxl

With openpyxl

With
**if sheet.cell(j, i).value**
i am testing if a certain cell in an excel sheet has a value.

The Problem: If there is a "0" in that cell the request give output "no"

Question: How do I change it, so that my request gives "Yes" as output if there is a "0" in that cell

Comment: Please provide a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use only `if sheet.cell(j, i).value` as the logical check, it will give False for both 0 and blank. So, you need to use `if sheet.cell(j, i).value is None`, in which case, it will return TRUE only when the cell is blank. A working example.

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
sheet=wb['Sheet2']
j=10
for i in range(1, 9):
    print("Data in cell is : ", sheet.cell(j, i).value)
    if sheet.cell(j, i).value is None:
        print("This is blank")
    else:
        print("This is not blank")
```

**Output**

```
Data in cell is :  1
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  2
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  3
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  None
This is blank
Data in cell is :  4
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  5
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  0
This is not blank
Data in cell is :  8
This is not blank
```